# Synchronization issue between the Django admin and the RESTful API endpoints

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin

The users I created in the Django admin interface are not showing in the /users/ endpoint and vice versa. Is there any potential synchronization issue between the Django admin and the RESTful API endpoints? Or will it be like this because of serialization?

I verified the User Model.  Model is correctly saved and migrated to the database.

Update #2

Model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Views for user:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def user_list_create_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        users = User.objects.all()
        print("Users:", users)  # Add this debug print
        serializer = UserSerializer(users, many=True)
        print("Serialized Data:", serializer.data)  # Add this debug print
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

@api_view(['GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE'])
def user_retrieve_update_delete_view(request, pk):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        serializer = UserSerializer(user, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
        return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE':
        user.delete()
        return JsonResponse({'message': 'User deleted successfully.'}, status=204)
```

Serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']
```

Comment: there is nothing like synchronization. your API and admin panel both uses the same database so the problem could be in your code. Please share your API and models.

Comment: Thanks @HemalPatel. I am trying to paste the code here, but it is too long. How should I share it?

Comment: just share models and the endpoint function you use for that users

Comment: Thanks. I added it to the original post.

Comment: Hey Hemal, I tried to reply, but looks like I don't have enough points to send message.

Comment: can you share entire Serializers.py?

Comment: from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Task, User

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email']

Comment: looks like problem is you're using your custom `User` model for your apis and `admin panel` by default uses `from django.contrib.auth.models import User
` which is already pre defined. So your data seems diff in both tables

Comment: Refer [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django-contrib-auth) There is no need to define `User` model unless you want to override/change fields. you can simply import and use that model as I mentioned in above comment

Comment: Thanks Hemal. Yeah you were right! The mismatch was happening due to using two different user models: your custom User model for APIs and the default User model from django.contrib.auth.models for the Django admin panel. This results in data being stored in two separate tables, and thus, they are not synchronized.

Comment: As you said, I am not defining the User model, and just importing the model. And it is working now for both admin panel and api endpoints.

Comment: yes that's correct way